# In PagerSlidingTabStrip for xamarin InflateException

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm using [PagerSlidingTabStrip-for-Xamarin.Android](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/PagerSlidingTabStrip-for-Xamarin.Android)
 Material Pager Sliding Tab Strip for Xamarin.Android lib

I import PagerSlidingTabStrip lib to my solution (using vs2013) and added to the xml com.refractored.PagerSlidingTabStrip

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
    <com.refractored.PagerSlidingTabStrip
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:pstsPaddingMiddle="true"
        app:pstsDividerWidth="1dp"
        app:pstsDividerPadding="12dp"
        app:pstsDividerColor="#50FFFFFF" />
<!--Change this to true if you want to center items-->
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" />
</LinearLayout>
```

But InflateException in SetContentView "com.refractored.PagerSlidingTabStrip"

```
05-15 14:26:59.848 D/Mono    (27464): DllImport searching in: '/system/lib/liblog.so' ('/system/lib/liblog.so').
05-15 14:26:59.848 D/Mono    (27464): Searching for '__android_log_print'.
05-15 14:26:59.848 D/Mono    (27464): Probing '__android_log_print'.
05-15 14:26:59.848 D/Mono    (27464): Found as '__android_log_print'.
05-15 14:26:59.863 I/MonoDroid(27464): UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:
05-15 14:26:59.878 I/MonoDroid(27464): Android.Views.InflateException: Exception of type 'Android.Views.InflateException' was thrown.
05-15 14:26:59.878 I/MonoDroid(27464): at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () <IL 0x00011, 0x00068>
05-15 14:26:59.878 I/MonoDroid(27464): at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallNonvirtualVoidMethod (intptr,intptr,intptr,Android.Runtime.JValue[]) [0x00084] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1353/86274adf/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/JNIEnv.g.cs:896
05-15 14:26:59.878 I/MonoDroid(27464): at Android.App.Activity.SetContentView (int) [0x00070] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1353/86274adf/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-21/src/generated/Android.App.Activity.cs:4763
05-15 14:26:59.878 I/MonoDroid(27464): at Android.App.Activity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (intptr,intptr,intptr) [0x00011] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1353/86274adf/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-21/src/generated/Android.App.Activity.cs:2380
05-15 14:26:59.878 I/MonoDroid(27464): at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.fc7251ee-439d-41fd-9acb-83d045358433 (intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00017, 0x00043>
05-15 14:26:59.878 I/MonoDroid(27464):   --- End of managed exception stack trace ---
05-15 14:26:59.878 I/MonoDroid(27464): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class com.refractored.PagerSlidingTabStrip
05-15 14:26:59.878 I/MonoDroid(27464):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
05-15 14:26:59.878 I/MonoDroid(27464):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
05-15 14:26:59.878 I/MonoDroid(27464):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
05-15 14:26:59.878 I/MonoDroid(27464):  at dalvik.system.Na05-15 14:26:59.878 I/MonoDroid(27464):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
05-15 14:26:59.878 I/MonoDroid(27464):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
05-15 14:26:59.878 I/MonoDroid(27464):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
05-15 14:26:59.878 I/MonoDroid(27464):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:308)
05-15 14:26:59.878 I/MonoDroid(27464):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1924)
05-15 14:26:59.878 I/MonoDroid(27464):  at scrollmenu.MainActivity.n_onCreate(Native Method)
05-15 14:26:59.878 I/MonoDroid(27464):  at scrollmenu.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28)
05-15 14:26:59.878 I/MonoDroid(27464):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
05-15 14:26:59.878 I/MonoDroid(27464):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
05-15 14:26:59.878 I/MonoDroid(27464):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
05-15 14:26:59.878 I/MonoDroid(27464):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
05-15 14:26:59.878 I/MonoDroid(27464):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
05-15 14:26:59.878 I/MonoDroid(27464):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
05-15 14:26:59.878 I/MonoDroid(27464):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-15 14:26:59.878 I/MonoDroid(27464):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-15 14:26:59.878 I/MonoDroid(27464):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4946)
05-15 14:26:59.878 I/MonoDroid(27464):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-15 14:26:59.878 I/MonoDroid(27464):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-15 14:26:59.878 I/MonoDroid(27464):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1036)
05-15 14:26:59.878 I/MonoDroid(27464):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:803)
05-15 14:26:59.878 I/MonoDroid(27464):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-15 14:26:59.878 I/MonoDroid(27464): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
05-15 14:26:59.878 I/MonoDroid(27464):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
05-15 14:26:59.878 I/MonoDroid(27464):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
05-15 14:26:59.878 I/MonoDroid(27464):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
05-15 14:26:59.878 I/MonoDroid(27464):  ... 23 more
05-15 14:26:59.878 I/MonoDroid(27464): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f01009c a=-1}
05-15 14:26:59.878 I/MonoDroid(27464):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2001)
05-15 14:26:59.878 I/MonoDroid(27464):  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
05-15 14:26:59.878 I/MonoDroid(27464):  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3444)
05-15 14:26:59.878 I/MonoDroid(27464):  at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:432)
05-15 14:26:59.878 I/MonoDroid(27464):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.<init>(FrameLayout.java:101)
05-15 14:26:59.878 I/MonoDroid(27464):  at android.widget.HorizontalScrollView.<init>(HorizontalScrollView.java:202)
05-15 14:26:59.878 I/MonoDroid(27464):  at android.widget.HorizontalScrollView.<init>(HorizontalScrollView.java:198)
05-15 14:26:59.878 I/MonoDroid(27464):  at com.refractored.PagerSlidingTabStrip.<init>(PagerSlidingTabStrip.java:38)
05-15 14:26:59.878 I/MonoDroid(27464):  ... 26 more
An unhandled exception occured.

05-15 14:27:01.188 E/mono    (27464): 
05-15 14:27:01.188 E/mono    (27464): Unhandled Exception:
05-15 14:27:01.188 E/mono    (27464): Android.Views.InflateException: Exception of type 'Android.Views.InflateException' was thrown.
05-15 14:27:01.188 E/mono    (27464): at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () <IL 0x00011, 0x00068>
05-15 14:27:01.188 E/mono    (27464): at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallNonvirtualVoidMethod (intptr,intptr,intptr,Android.Runtime.JValue[]) [0x00084] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1353/86274adf/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/JNIEnv.g.cs:896
05-15 14:27:01.188 E/mono    (27464): at Android.App.Activity.SetContentView (int) [0x00070] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1353/86274adf/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-21/src/generated/Android.App.Activity.cs:4763
05-15 14:27:01.188 E/mono    (27464): at ScrollMenu.MainActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle) [0x00009] in d:\j.vso\bbalde\android\ScrollMenu\ScrollMenu\MainActivity.cs:22
05-15 14:27:01.188 E/mono    (27464): at Android.App.Activity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (intptr,intptr,intptr) [0x00011] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1353/86274adf/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-21/src/generated/Android.App.Activity.cs:2380
05-15 14:27:01.188 E/mono    (27464): at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.fc7251ee-439d-41fd-9acb-83d045358433 (intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00017, 0x00043>
05-15 14:27:01.188 E/mono    (27464): 
05-15 14:27:01.188 E/mono    (27464):   --- End of managed exception stack trace ---
05-15 14:27:01.188 E/mono    (27464): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class com.refractored.PagerSlidingTabStrip
05-15 14:27:01.188 E/mono    (27464):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
05-15 14:27:01.188 E/mono    (27464):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
05-15 14:27:01.188 E/mono    (27464):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
05-15 14:27:01.188 E/mono    (27464):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
05-15 14:27:01.188 E/mono    (27464):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
05-15 14:27:01.188 E/mono    (27464):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
05-15 14:27:01.188 E/mono    (27464):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:308)
05-15 14:27:01.188 E/mono    (27464):   at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1924)
05-15 14:27:01.188 E/mono    (27464):   at scrollmenu.MainActivity.n_onCreate(Native Method)
05-15 14:27:01.188 E/mono    (27464):   at scrollmenu.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28)
05-15 14:27:01.188 E/mono    (27464):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
05-15 14:27:01.188 E/mono    (27464):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
```

The activity can call methods on the  library
So it did not connect library..?

Answer (score 1):

If you use MvvmCross framework you must register PagerSlidingTabStrip assembly on Setup class:

```
public class Setup : MvxAndroidSetup
{
    protected override IList<Assembly> AndroidViewAssemblies {
        get {
            var assemlies = base.AndroidViewAssemblies;
            assemlies.Add(typeof(ViewPager).Assembly);
            assemlies.Add(typeof(PagerSlidingTabStrip).Assembly);
            return assemlies;
        }
    }
}
```